# In this linear equation system, find the $a,b,c$ values such that...

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

> Consider this linear equations system:
>
> \begin{align*} \begin{pmatrix} a & 1 & 1\\  1 & a & 1 \\  1 & 1 & 1
>  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x\\  y\\  z \end{pmatrix}=
>  \begin{pmatrix} b\\  c\\  2 \end{pmatrix} \end{align*}
>
> 1. Determine the $a,b,c$ values such that the system has a unique solution.
> 2. To those $a,b,c$ values such that the system has a non unique solution, find all the possible solutions.

We have that:

\begin{align*}
ax+y+z&=b\\x+ay+z&=c\\x+y+z&=2
\end{align*}

Then:

\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
a & 1 & 1 & \vdots & b\\ 
1 & a & 1 & \vdots & c\\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & \vdots & 2
\end{pmatrix}\sim \cdots \sim
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \vdots & \frac{b-2}{a-1}\\ 
0 & 1 & \frac{1}{a} & \vdots & \frac{c(a-1)-(b-2)}{a(a-1)}\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & \vdots & \frac{a \left [ 2(a-1)-(b-2) \right ]}{(a-1)^{2}}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

But I don't know how to continue to solve **1** and **2**. What am I doing wrong or how would you solve it? I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Didn't check your work but, One more row operation to remove the $1/a$

Comment: Oh God! That's true. But then, how would I determine the $a,b,c$ values to solve 1 and 2?

Comment: For "always a solution", one way is to determine when $\det A$ is nonzero. It turns out $\det A = (a-1)^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I would solve the first question: A quick check shows that $\det A=(a-1)^2$, so there is a unique solution unless $a=1$.

A hands-on approach without any theory works too: Note that $x+y+z=2$ and so
$$b-2=(ax+y+z)-(x+y+z)=(a-1)x,$$
$$c-2=(x+ay+z)-(x+y+z)=(a-1)y,$$
which shows that if $a\neq1$ then
$$x=\frac{b-2}{a-1}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad y=\frac{c-2}{a-1},$$
and hence
$$z=2-x-y=\frac{2a-b-c+2}{a-1}.$$
So if $a\neq1$ there is a unique solution, for any value of $b$ and $c$.

---

As for the second question: If $a=1$ then it is necessary and sufficient that $b=c=2$ for a solution to exist.  The solutions are all $x$, $y$ and $z$ such that $x+y+z=2$. That is, all triplets of the form
$$(x,y,2-x-y).$$